# getting syntax error when using ionic run android

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am currently trying out my app using a samsung tablet SM-T113NU.  When I try ionic run android, i am getting just a white screen.  So, i opened up chrome inspect and I got a syntax error saying there is an unexpected token "(" in line 187.  Here is line 187:

```
inputVerificationCode() { 
// some code}
```

Now, when I connect my samsung S4, the app works fine and I can see my main page.  My S4 is on Android version 5.0.1 while my Samsung tablet is at version 4.4.4.  Does this have any effect on the app?  (my tablet says it is currently updated so maybe it does not have an official v5.

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from ionic forum:  needed to change inputVerificationCode() to inputVerificationCode: function()